# How to use multiple classes with condition in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, django-rest-framework, angular6

Im trying to use a condition for multiple classes selection on [ngClass] :

```
<td>
<span 
      [ngClass]="{
             'badge badge-success': {{ server.type }} === 'PRODUCTION',
             'badge badge-danger': {{ server.type }} === 'TEST',
             'badge badge-warning': {{ server.type }} === 'DEV'
              }">
</span>
</td>
```

I know that [ngClass] not works with {{ }} , Im getting my data from restapi django app , what the alternative way to do that? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use `{{}}` with `[ngClass]`, so just remove it.

Try this -

```
 [ngClass]="{
             'badge badge-success': server.type  === 'PRODUCTION',
             'badge badge-danger':  server.type  === 'TEST',
             'badge badge-warning': server.type  === 'DEV'
              }">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the  `[ { key: class}[ expression ]]` to handle multiple conditions

```
<span class="badge " ng-class="[{'PRODUCTION':'badge-success', 'TEST':'badge-danger', 'DEV':'badge-warning'}[ server.type]]"></div>
```